# I want to remove \u00a9 , \u201d and characters like that from my string in given dictionary (python).

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
d = {
    "key": "Impress the playing crowd with these classic "
           "Playing Cards \u00a9 Personalized Coasters.These beautiful"
           " coasters are made from glass, and measure approximately 4\u201d x 4\u201d (inches)"
           ".Great to look at, and lovely to the touch.There are 4 coasters in a set.We have "
           "created this exclusive design for all card lovers.Each coaster is a different suit, "
           "with the underneath.Make your next Bridge, or Teen Patti session uber-personal!"
           "Will look great on the bar, or any tabletop.Gift Designed for: Couples, Him, "
           "HerOccasion:Diwali, Bridge, Anniversary, Birthday"}
```

i have tried the replace function on it but didn't work.

```
s = d[key].replace('\u00a9','')
```

Comment: be aware that `\u00a9` is the copyright symbol. Removing that may have legal consequences.

Comment: Concur, removing the characters you cannot understand seems like the wrong way to solve this problem.  (The actual text has much more severe problems, but I guess that's out of scope for this site.)

Comment: Please explain "but didn't work". What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @André write that out as an answer, it seems to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: @jace - i was expecting the replacement of these characters with '' empty string.

andre - let me try your solution. thanks ALL anyways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove accents in a python unicode string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: You _should not_ remove unicode characters - you hhave to DFEAL with then - please read: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remove all Unicode characters from a string, you can use `string.encode("ascii", "ignore")`.

It tries to encode the string to ASCII, and the second parameter `ignore` tells it to ignore characters that it can't convert (all Unicode chars) instead of throwing an exception as it would normally do without that second parameter, so it returns a string with only the chars that could successfully be converted, thus removing all Unicode characters.

Example usage :

```
unicodeString = "Héllò StàckOvèrflow"
print(unicodeString.encode("ascii", "ignore")) # prints 'Hll StckOvrflow'
```

More info : [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 3):

```
d['key'].decode('unicode-escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

is what you are looking for

```
>>> d = {
...     "key": "Impress the playing crowd with these classic "
...            "Playing Cards \u00a9 Personalized Coasters.These beautiful"
...            " coasters are made from glass, and measure approximately 4\u201d x 4\u201d (inches)"
...            ".Great to look at, and lovely to the touch.There are 4 coasters in a set.We have "
...            "created this exclusive design for all card lovers.Each coaster is a different suit, "
...            "with the underneath.Make your next Bridge, or Teen Patti session uber-personal!"
...            "Will look great on the bar, or any tabletop.Gift Designed for: Couples, Him, "
...            "HerOccasion:Diwali, Bridge, Anniversary, Birthday"}
>>> d['key'].decode('unicode-escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
'Impress the playing crowd with these classic Playing Cards  Personalized Coasters.These beautiful coasters are made from glass, and measure approximately 4 x 4 (inches).Great to look at, and lovely to the touch.There are 4 coasters in a set.We have created this exclusive design for all card lovers.Each coaster is a different suit, with the underneath.Make your next Bridge, or Teen Patti session uber-personal!Will look great on the bar, or any tabletop.Gift Designed for: Couples, Him, HerOccasion:Diwali, Bridge, Anniversary, Birthday'
>>>
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) doesn't have a `decode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove characters represented by unicode escape sequences, you need to use a unicode string.

For example,

```
s = d[key].replace(u'\u00a9', '')
```

However, as people have mentioned in comments, removing the copyright symbol might be a very bad idea, though it depends on what you're actually doing with the string.

Comment: (for what it's worth, `d['key'].replace("\u00a9","")` worked as intended for me on Python3.3)

Comment: @AdamSmith it makes a difference in Python2.7

Comment: yeah i was trying on py2.7